# How do I limit protected inheritance of members to only one or a few generation(s)?

Tags: c++, inheritance, private, protected, restriction

My `class Dad` provides some `protected` methods, that its children will need, even if it doesn't actually know yet who these children will be.

```
class Dad
{
protected:
    void method()
    {
        // some amazing stuff (I swear)
    };
};
```

The actual inheriting `class Child: public Dad`, in the current implementation of my program, has decided to be derived itself into several classes `class GrandKid1: Child`, `class GrandKid2: Child` etc.

But, for the sake of safety and organisation, `Child` prefers the grandkids not to be able to call the `method()` by themselves. How do I prevent them from doing this?

Obviously, the following naive code yields a linker error:

```
class Child: public Dad
{
private:
    void method();
};
```

How do I make `Child` stop the propagation of the `protected` member `method()` to its own derived classes?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `using` directive to put member into another section.

```
class Dad
{
protected:
    void Method() { std::cout << "Dad"; }
};

class Child : public Dad
{
private:
    using Dad::Method;
};

class GrandChild : public Child
{
public:
    void f1() { Method(); } // Generates compilation error
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If your actual code is not much more complex than your example, you can just use `friend`.

```
class Child;

class Dad
{
    friend class Child;

private:
    void method () {}
};

class Child : public Dad
{
    void someothermethod ()
    {
        method ();
    }
};
```

Comment: Not too bad, or even a `DadChildAttorney` to control the granularity of the access to `Dad`'s private members. The snag is that, by the time `Dad` is coded, it has no idea of which classes will inheritate from itself. And `Dad` doesn't actually care of whether or not `Child` will have grandkids or not, or if `Daughter: Dad` will prefer its own `GrandDaughters: Daughter` to be able to freely access `method()` etc. Does that make sense? The program's "core" made of `Dad` etc.. cannot be influenced by the actual various "kids" `Child: Dad` or `Daughter: Dad` that'll actually use it later..

Comment: So your actual code is more complex and @purecuteness' answer is fit. In both cases actually as his way is much "cleaner".

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually *define* the member function, not only declare it:

```
class Child: public Dad
{
private:
    void method() {}
};
```

Comment: So for `Child` to call `Dad`'s `method`, it has to say `Dad::method()`, right? But then the grandhildren can do exactly the same, can't they?

Comment: Will this not make `Child` unable to call the "true" `method()` itself? I mean: each time `Child::method()` will be called in *Child.cpp*, the empty block `{}` will execute and not the `// amazing stuff`, am I right? @TonyK and then, yeah, the Grandkids are still free to use `Dad::method()`, aren't they?